# How to show an alpha-numeric keyboard in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, android-studio

I want to show an **alpha-numeric** keyboard in my React-Native App. I tried many values in `keyboardType` prop but it doesn't work for me.

If anyone knows how I achieve this please share your ideas.

Thanks in Advance.

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: Check this out: https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/ You can see how the keyboard would look for each `keyboardType` value on Android and iOS.

Comment: Thanks @SagarShakya for your response but I tried it already in android ```visible-password``` works fine. But for iOS it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**keyboardType:**

Determines which keyboard to open, e.g.numeric.

See screenshots of all the types [Here](https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/)

The following values work across platforms:

- default
- number-pad
- decimal-pad
- numeric
- email-address
- phone-pad
- url

**IOS Only**

The following values work on iOS only:

- ascii-capable
- numbers-and-punctuation
- name-phone-pad
- web-search
- twitter

**Android Only**
The following values work on Android only:

- visible-password

> Type
>
> `enum('default', 'email-address', 'numeric', 'phone-pad', 'ascii-capable', 'numbers-and-punctuation', 'url', 'number-pad', 'name-phone-pad', 'decimal-pad', 'twitter', 'web-search', 'visible-password')`

Comment: I already tried it bro. But It didn't work.

Comment: you are using and third party keyboard?

Comment: No bro I'm not using any third party libraries.